# python - removing punctuation in a list of sentences using 1 line of code

Tags: python, string

So I have a list of sentences and I want to remove punctuation from each sentences. I can remove it in this manner:

```
textList = ['This is bad.', 'You, me, him are going']

from string import punctuation

for text in textList:
    for p in punctuation:
        text = text.replace(p,'')
    print(text)
```

But I want to modify the list content and do it one line. Something like this:

```
# obviously this does not work
textList = [(text.replace(p,'') for p in punctuation) for text in textList]
```

What is the proper way to do it?

Comment: Why do you have to do it in one line?

Comment: cleaner code and I need to enclose it in bracket to make into a list. Otherwise I have to do list.append() everytime.

Comment: I don't think squeezing something that "logically" is a nested loop into a single line is "cleaner code". The Python mantra is that explicitness is a good thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python 2, you can use [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) like below:

```
res = [s.translate(None, string.punctuation) for s in textList]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> textList = ['This is bad.', 'You, me, him are going']
>>> res = [s.translate(None, string.punctuation) for s in textList]
>>> res
['This is bad', 'You me him are going']
```

In Python 3, you can use [str.maketrans()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) like this:

```
res = [s.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)) for s in textList]
```

**Note:** Using your approach, you can do:

```
res = []

for text in textList:
    new_text = ''.join(c for c in text if c not in string.punctuation)
    res.append(new_text)
```

In one line:

```
res = [''.join(c for c in text if c not in string.punctuation) for text in textList]
```

Comment: or using map : `textList = map(lambda x: x.translate(None, string.punctuation), textList)`

Comment: @AshishRanjan list comprehension is more pythonic than map :)

Comment: I got this error: `TypeError: translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given)`

Comment: @ettanany yup that's why didn't post it as an answer, was just suggesting an alternative. also, comprehension will faster than map with a lambda

Comment: Nevermind my previous error. Somehow I have to do it like this in Python 3. `res= [s.translate(str.maketrans('','',string.punctuation)) for s in textList]`

Comment: @addicted That's true, I edited my answer to also include the case for Python 3

Comment: @ettanany any idea why we cannot use the text.replace(p,'') for p in punctuation inside a list bracket?

Comment: @addicted among the issues that you have is that your resulted list contains generator expressions, please take a look at the edit to see a solution using your approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think the fact that you're trying to solve this in a one-liner points out that this is more of a riddle, so I'll not answer with a complete solution.

So, there's loads of ways to do this. You could build a regular expression, replacing all punctuation with nothing at once, for example.

But, if we're going to stay with the idea of your last line of code, I think `reduce()` is the python built-in that you're looking for!

Comment: It is not actually a riddle. I want to do a one-liner but I cant figure out the correct syntax to do it. I simply wants to convert that `from  p in punctuation: text.replace(p,'')` into a 1 liner I can enclose with brackets to make a list.